# Can we use TFS 2013 Release Management for SharePoint 2013 projects?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tfs

Can we use TFS 2013 Release Management for SharePoint 2013 projects? I have googled on these lines and couldn't find any links. I have not worked with Release Management, so no idea if that handles SharePoint deployments as well. Do we have any ready made deployment tools for SharePoint? If we have, do they integrate with TFS ? If Release Management supports SP deployments also,has any team used it in real time or at least for evaluation? Our team is planning to use RM for SP deployments. So any ideas will be of great help for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what solution do you build (farm solutions or SharePoint apps) and what is your staging or testing environment (SharePoint on-premises or O365). Here is some link that could help:

1. [SharePoint 2013 Continues Integration with TFS 2013 Release and Build Management](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25846.sharepoint-2013-continues-integration-with-tfs-2013-release-and-build-management-part-1.aspx)
2. [ALM for SharePoint Apps: Configuring a TFS Build Server with Team Foundation Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/08/15/alm-for-sharepoint-apps-configuring-a-tfs-build-server-with-team-foundation-service.aspx)
3. [SP2010 Continuous Integration](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/06/sp2010-continuous-integrationpt-1.html). A bit old but very interesting.